# flexslider and background image not shown in ipad

Tags: jquery, cs-cart

I'm using cs cart. Here I have used background image and flexslider for display products. Its working fine. unfortunately, It is not visible in ipad device.

In mozila ctrl+shift+m ipad size view is working. But when i check in the device its not working. How to resolve this issue ?

here is my coding.

```
<div class="section parallax full-screen dark nomargin noborder" style="background-image: url('skins/sailorsandcrooks/customer/css/images/parallax/1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4">
    <div align="center">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="flexslider carousel">
                <ul class="slides">
                    {assign var="image_h" value="400"}
                    {assign var="text_h" value="90"}
                    {assign var="cellspacing" value="2"}
                    {math equation="3 * cellspacing + image_h + text_h" assign="item_height" cellspacing=$cellspacing image_h=$image_h text_h=$text_h}
                    {foreach from=$items item="product" name="for_products"}
                    <li class="item">
                        {assign var="obj_id" value="scr_`$block.block_id`000`$product.product_id`"}
                        {assign var="img_object_type" value="product"}
                        {include file="common_templates/image.tpl" assign="object_img" image_width=$block.properties.thumbnail_width image_height=$block.properties.thumbnail_width images=$product.main_pair no_ids=true object_type=$img_object_type show_thumbnail="Y"}
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="{$cellspacing}" border="0" width="{$item_width}">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="center product-image" style="height: {$image_h}px;">
                                    <div class="product-image">
                                        <a href="{"products.view?product_id=`$product.product_id`"|fn_url}">{$object_img}</a>
                                        <a href="{"products.view?product_id=`$product.product_id`"|fn_url}">
                                           {assign var="image_details" value=$product.product_id|fn_get_image_pairs:"product":"A":true:true}
                                           {assign var="first_image" value=0}
                                           {if $image_details}
                                           {foreach from=$image_details key=k item="roll_image"}
                                           {if $first_image eq 0}
                                           {$image_details.detailed.http_image_path}
                                           <img src="{$roll_image.detailed.http_image_path}" alt="{$lang.image}" height="{$image_h}px" width="{$item_width}px" />
                                            {capture assign=first_image}{$first_image+1}{/capture}
                                            {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                            {/if}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="prod-details">
                                        {if $block.properties.hide_add_to_cart_button == "Y"}
                                        {assign var="_show_add_to_cart" value=false}
                                        {else}
                                        {assign var="_show_add_to_cart" value=true}
                                        {/if}
                                        {strip}
                                        {if $block.properties.item_number == "Y"}{$smarty.foreach.for_products.iteration}.&nbsp;{/if}
                                        {include file="blocks/list_templates/simple_list.tpl" product=$product show_trunc_name=false show_price=false show_add_to_cart=$_show_add_to_cart but_role="text"}
                                        {/strip}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="center compact" style="height: {$text_h}px;">
                                    {if $block.properties.hide_add_to_cart_button == "Y"}
                                    {assign var="_show_add_to_cart" value=false}
                                    {else}
                                    {assign var="_show_add_to_cart" value=true}
                                    {/if}
                                    {strip}
                                    {if $block.properties.item_number == "Y"}{$smarty.foreach.for_products.iteration}.&nbsp;{/if}
                                    {include file="blocks/list_templates/simple_list.tpl" product=$product show_trunc_name=true show_price=true show_add_to_cart=$_show_add_to_cart but_role="text"}
                                    {/strip}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-controlls clickable" style=""><div class="owl-pagination"><div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div></div><div class="owl-buttons"><div class="owl-prev disabled">prev</div><div class="owl-next">next</div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how large is your background image?  ipads won't show an image if it is over a certain size

Comment: it just 448px height.. The slider also not working even i removed background image

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you to install [Firebug Lite Bookmarklet](http://iosbookmarklets.com/tutorials/firebug-lite-bookmarklet/) and check if any JS errors are displayed in the console. They can be a reason